# Is it possible to alter column to decimal in MS Access 2007+?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, decimal, alter

Is it possible to alter column to decimal in MS Access 2007+? This is my code: `ALTER TABLE [test] ALTER COLUMN [columnName] DECIMAL(18,1)`

Comment: Ok I did it. Its not possible in query of ms access but in OLEDB its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible in query of ms access but in OLEDB its possible.

Answer (score 0):

`DECIMAL(18,1)` is no Access datatype.
Either you link it to an MSSQL Server or you use a MS Access datatype.

[Here you will find a msdn article on MS Access datatypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  (use the types in the second column for your ALTER Query)

```
ALTER TABLE [test] ALTER COLUMN [columnName] LONG
```

Best Regards, Bruellhusten